# Has anyone used Jaxer in production?

Tags: performance, aptana, jaxer

Has anyone used [Jaxer](http://web.archive.org/web/20090803092709/http://www.aptana.com:80/Jaxer) in a production environment, I am curious as to how it holds up compared to something like php, ruby, etc. and if anyone knows of any pitfalls to using it that are well known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I would put an answer on this, as to not leave it hanging. This answer is not directly related to Jaxer, but since this question was asked. Technologies such as Node.JS have came out, bringing with it the same ideas and technology Jaxer was proposing and showing that Javascript can be viable on the backend of the web technology stack just as it is on the front end.

Answer (score 3):

@Stu: Not necessarily, maybe there's a bunch of people using it and having no issues. I love the concept having to only write validations once, using one language for everything both client and server side sounds like a interesting approach.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, if you have to ask this question, it is a bad idea.

Comment: I agree. There's enough about web development on the web that someone would write about it if it were great.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this [Url](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-jaxer/index.html?ca=dgr-jw64wa-aj-jaxer&S_TACT=105AGY46&S_CMP=GRsitejw64) to my post I found it today, it has some information regarding the subject but no real "performance" information.

Answer (score 0):

I've posted a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98915/is-anyone-familiar-with-jaxer-im-looking-for-pros-and-cons) and gotten a response...  Not much information out there to be had yet.

I did come across this set of [performance benchmarks](http://www.aptana.com/taxonomy/term/14), and I've also posted a question about [object-oriented development in Jaxer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109762/defining-objects-when-using-jaxer) which I think might leave something to be desired.