# Execute CMD command by webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, security, cmd

Is it possible for a webpage to excecute a windows CMD command on client side?
I have searched web for this query but could not find any answers.

Comment: No, of course not. Think of the security implications.

Comment: No this would be a security disaster, if any website could run commands on a local machine. This is why ActiveX no longer exists.

Comment: What can client-side Javascript do? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1404376/447901

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible.
This would give huge challenges on security.
Think for example about malicious use of this function where can be taken control of the local machine from the outside.

Comment: What if i am willing to give all the permissions it needs ?